# How to retrieve rows (values) one after one from a database (Mysql) using a loop

Tags: java, jdbc

```
int score;
sql = "SELECT score FROM scores";
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
int score;

while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < al.getNumOfDepartments(); i++) {
        Department a = al.getDepartment(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < jl.getNumOfJudges(); j++) {
            score = rs.getInt("score");
            Judge member = jl.getJudge(j);
            Score s = new Score(score, member);
            a.addScore(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Need help on this code, I'm trying to assign a score given by judges (3 judges in this case) to a department,the scores are stored in a database. The problem is every score is given three times to a single department by a single judge, but it should not be like this. In fact every judge can assign one score to a department . This is a pure nested loop problem i guess, but sinds i'm just an engineer student even not specialized in computer sciences i couldn't figure it out my self. thanks for help!

so i should every time retrieve one row not more that's it.

this is the rest of the code

```
package main;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import model.Afdeling;
import model.AfdelingenLijst;
import model.JuryLedenLijst;
import model.JuryLid;
import model.Score;
public class afdelingenJuryledenScoresLezen implements ActionListener {

    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Audit";
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "root";
     AfdelingenLijst al;
     JuryLedenLijst jl;
     JuryLid lid;

     public afdelingenJuryledenScoresLezen(AfdelingenLijst al, JuryLedenLijst jl) 
        {
         this.al = al;
         this.jl=jl;
        }
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql;
            sql = "SELECT ID, Afdeling FROM Afdelingen";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            int ID;
            String naam;
            while (rs.next())
             {
                ID = rs.getInt("ID");
                naam = rs.getString("Afdeling");
                Afdeling a = new Afdeling(ID, naam);
                al.voegAfdelingToe(a);
             }


            sql = "SELECT ID, Jurylid FROM Juryleden";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            int id;
            String jurylid;
            while (rs.next())
             {
                id = rs.getInt("ID");
                jurylid = rs.getString("Jurylid");
                JuryLid lid = new JuryLid(id, jurylid);
                jl.voegJuryLidToe(lid);
             }
            sql = "SELECT score FROM scores";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            int score;
            while (rs.next()){
            for (int i=0; i<al.getAantalAfdelingen(); i++){
                        Afdeling a = al.getAfdeling(i);
                        for (int j=0; j<jl.getAantalJuryLeden(); j++)
                        {
                        score= rs.getInt("score");
                        JuryLid lid = jl.getJuryLid(j);
                        Score s = new Score(score, lid);
                        a.voegScoreToe(s);
                    }
                }
            }

            al.setAfdelingen(al.getAfdelingen());

            rs.beforeFirst();

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();

            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();

            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();

            System.out.println("\nGoodbye!");
         }
         catch (Exception ex) {}
        }
      }
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Can you change function and variable name to english, would be easier to assist..
As it is, you will loop the 2nd time a number of time equal to jl.getAantalJuryLeden, not sure what it is

Comment: Note also that `"Need help on this code"` is a terrible title for a StackOverflow question as it tells us nothing whatsoever of use. We already know that you "need help" with your code, else you wouldn't be asking a question. In the future, please consider using much more informative question titles, ones that summarize your actual problem. Doing this will help you get better help. Please also go through the [help] and the [ask] to see how to better use this site.

Comment: i'm sorry if my post is difficult to follow, this is my first experience with Stackoverflow i'll try to explain it on a better manner.